# Found array with 0 feature(s)

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I implemented the Principal Feature Analysis algorithm and it raised `Found array with 0 feature(s)`.

```
thresh2 = 0.01
class PFA(object):
    def __init__(self, diff_n_features = 2, q=None, explained_var = thresh2):
        self.q = q
        self.diff_n_features = diff_n_features
        self.explained_var = explained_var

    def fit(self, X):
        sc = StandardScaler()
        X = sc.fit_transform(X)

        pca = PCA().fit(X)
        
        if not self.q:
            explained_variance = pca.explained_variance_ratio_
            cumulative_expl_var = [sum(explained_variance[:i+1]) for i in range(len(explained_variance))]
            for i,j in enumerate(cumulative_expl_var):
                if j >= self.explained_var:
                    q = i
                    break
                    
        A_q = pca.components_.T[:,:q]
        
        clusternumber = min([q + self.diff_n_features, X.shape[1]])
        
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters= clusternumber).fit(A_q)
        clusters = kmeans.predict(A_q)
        cluster_centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_

        dists = defaultdict(list)
        for i, c in enumerate(clusters):
            dist = euclidean_distances([A_q[i, :]], [cluster_centers[c, :]])[0][0]
            dists[c].append((i, dist))

        self.indices_ = [sorted(f, key=lambda x: x[1])[0][0] for f in dists.values()]
        self.features_ = X[:, self.indices_]
        
    def fit_transform(self,X):    
        sc = StandardScaler()
        X = sc.fit_transform(X)

        pca = PCA().fit(X)
        
        if not self.q:
            explained_variance = pca.explained_variance_ratio_
            cumulative_expl_var = [sum(explained_variance[:i+1]) for i in range(len(explained_variance))]
            for i,j in enumerate(cumulative_expl_var):
                if j >= self.explained_var:
                    q = i
                    break
                    
        A_q = pca.components_.T[:,:q]
        
        clusternumber = min([q + self.diff_n_features, X.shape[1]])
        
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters= clusternumber).fit(A_q)
        clusters = kmeans.predict(A_q)
        cluster_centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_

        dists = defaultdict(list)
        for i, c in enumerate(clusters):
            dist = euclidean_distances([A_q[i, :]], [cluster_centers[c, :]])[0][0]
            dists[c].append((i, dist))

        self.indices_ = [sorted(f, key=lambda x: x[1])[0][0] for f in dists.values()]
        self.features_ = X[:, self.indices_]
        
        return X[:, self.indices_]
    
    def transform(self, X):
        return X[:, self.indices_]

pfa = PFA(diff_n_features=1, explained_var= thresh2)
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 pfa.fit_transform(subset3.T)
      3 featurekeys = [subset3.T.keys().tolist()[i] for i in pfa.indices_]
      4 subset4 = subset3.T[featurekeys].T

Input In [6], in PFA.fit_transform(self, X)
     52 A_q = pca.components_.T[:,:q]
     54 clusternumber = min([q + self.diff_n_features, X.shape[1]])
---> 56 kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters= clusternumber).fit(A_q)
     57 clusters = kmeans.predict(A_q)
     58 cluster_centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/_kmeans.py:1417, in KMeans.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1390 """Compute k-means clustering.
   1391 
   1392 Parameters
   (...)
   1413     Fitted estimator.
   1414 """
   1415 self._validate_params()
-> 1417 X = self._validate_data(
   1418     X,
   1419     accept_sparse="csr",
   1420     dtype=[np.float64, np.float32],
   1421     order="C",
   1422     copy=self.copy_x,
   1423     accept_large_sparse=False,
   1424 )
   1426 self._check_params_vs_input(X)
   1428 random_state = check_random_state(self.random_state)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:565, in BaseEstimator._validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    563     raise ValueError("Validation should be done on X, y or both.")
    564 elif not no_val_X and no_val_y:
--> 565     X = check_array(X, input_name="X", **check_params)
    566     out = X
    567 elif no_val_X and not no_val_y:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:940, in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator, input_name)
    938     n_features = array.shape[1]
    939     if n_features < ensure_min_features:
--> 940         raise ValueError(
    941             "Found array with %d feature(s) (shape=%s) while"
    942             " a minimum of %d is required%s."
    943             % (n_features, array.shape, ensure_min_features, context)
    944         )
    946 if copy:
    947     if xp.__name__ in {"numpy", "numpy.array_api"}:
    948         # only make a copy if `array` and `array_orig` may share memory`

ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(14239, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by KMeans.
```

Input:

`subset3.shape`

```
(14239, 261)
```

`subset3`

```
pd.DataFrame({'TCGA.KL.8325.01': {'cg00002837': -1.25173175676829,
  'cg00003287': -2.3899812965651,
  'cg00060374': 0.875920559926622,
  'cg00107970': 0.511415598706767},
 'TCGA.KL.8326.01': {'cg00002837': -0.173745458536387,
  'cg00003287': -2.06716256997178,
  'cg00060374': 2.02775309720088,
  'cg00107970': 0.947678035068017},
 'TCGA.KL.8327.01': {'cg00002837': -0.191837975800569,
  'cg00003287': -2.27833389547341,
  'cg00060374': 3.05807890807175,
  'cg00107970': -0.271627536828045},
 'TCGA.KL.8328.01': {'cg00002837': -1.61298636852405,
  'cg00003287': -1.71040824401497,
  'cg00060374': -0.33733954111133,
  'cg00107970': -1.80481637233918}})
```

Comment: `A_q = pca.components_.T[:,:q+1]`